# how to display ansi color using terminal-table

Tags: ruby

I'm using terminal-table to display some info.
There is a row that I need to display in some color.
I'm using Curses gem to refresh the screen.

I'm using this code:

```
rows = []
rows << "\033[31;1;4mHello\033[0m"
```

But this code isn't working.
The string with color isn't rendered.

Comment: I've never used that gem, but probably you should follow [this example](https://github.com/tj/terminal-table/pull/11#issue-1922523) to add colors in your table.

Comment: thanks, it works but I'm using Curses to update terminal values and that lib doesn't support colors.